# How to parameterize a lambda which is used as an argument to another lambda

Tags: c++, lambda

```
#include <iostream>

// How to parameterize this lambda and use it in the second lambda?
auto print = []() { std::cout << "in print" << std::endl; };

auto repeat = [](auto function, const int num_repeat) {
  int ctr = 0;
  while (ctr++ < num_repeat) {
    function();
  }
};

int main() {
  repeat(print, 3);
  return 0;
}
```

In the above c++ example I have used a lambda function `print` (which does not accept any arguments) in another lambda `repeat` as an argument. This works with the following output:

```
$ ./a.out 
in print
in print
in print
```

However, I want to pass an argument (or a variable list of arguments) to `print` and use it in `repeat`. Is it possible? For example, the modified `print` would look like:

```
auto print = [](std::string& name) { std::cout << "hello " << name << std::endl; };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fail to see the problem?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// How to parameterize this lambda and use it in the second lambda?
auto print = []( const std::string& s ) { std::cout << s << std::endl; };

auto repeat = [](auto function, const int num_repeat) {
  int ctr = 0;
  while (ctr++ < num_repeat) {
    function( "call #" + std::to_string( ctr ) );
  }
};

int main() {
  repeat(print, 3);
}
```

What did you try that *didn't* work?

Answer (score 0):

This might help (from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda))

```
// generic lambda, operator() is a template with two parameters
auto glambda = [](auto a, auto&& b) { return a < b; };
bool b = glambda(3, 3.14); // ok

// generic lambda, operator() is a template with one parameter
auto vglambda = [](auto printer) {
    return [=](auto&&... ts) // generic lambda, ts is a parameter pack
    { 
        printer(std::forward<decltype(ts)>(ts)...);
        return [=] { printer(ts...); }; // nullary lambda (takes no parameters)
    };
};
auto p = vglambda([](auto v1, auto v2, auto v3) { std::cout << v1 << v2 << v3; });
auto q = p(1, 'a', 3.14); // outputs 1a3.14
q();                      // outputs 1a3.14
```